# Azure CDN for cloud service requests are forwarded to <myapp>.cloudapp.net instead of my custom hostname binding

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

As mentioned in the title above I have a cloudservice with a WebRole that runs a web app www.myappname.com. I have taken all necessary steps to enable serving of CDN content from my app using url rewrite module on IIS. This works fine but:

1. The requests coming in from CDN are forwarded to .cloudapp.net instead of my custom hostname binding. I cannot find any place to change this in my configuration. When I create a new CDN endpoint my options for setting the ORIGIN DOMAIN are limited to my cloud service endpoints
2. Say I got a custom domain name for my cloud service CDN endpoint (ex. static.appnamecdn.com). What happens when I make request with https? I don't see any place to register the "static.appnamecdn.com" 's ssl certificate. Isn't something like this required?

Comment: I don't see a reason why my question is not useful. So why the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help icon on the Create CDN Endpoint screen (Azure Management Portal) I got my answer to the second point above:

> If you choose to enable HTTPS for your CDN endpoint, keep in mind the
>    following points:
>
> - You must use the certificate provided by the CDN. Third party    certificates are not supported.
> - You must use the CDN domain to    access content. HTTPS support is not available for custom domain    names (CNAMEs) since the CDN does
>     not support custom certificates at    this time.
> - HTTPS is from the CDN to the client only. Requests from    the CDN to the content provider (Storage Account or hosted service)    are
>     still made using HTTP.

Comment: as of Apr 16, 2014 the [feedback site](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169397-cdn/suggestions/1332683-access-to-cdn-over-ssl-https) for azure states that this feature is currently planned. So the answer is not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, I don't think that is possible...Azure's CDN unfortunately is somewhat limited in its options.

As to the 2nd, as was said in the other answer, it's not possible to use HTTPS with a custom domain name :/